how many calls per handler are allowed in the queue
Maybe someone can tell me how to calculate the size of ipc.server.handler.queue.size core-site.xml
From the description of the property:
Specifies how many calls for each handler are allowed in the queue. This value allows you to determine the maximum size of the call queue by multiplying the number of handler threads.
What is meant by handler threads?
Please help me figure it out.
